# File not found while giving URI request to get request token in Oauth authorization flow (to access Yahoo API)

Tags: oauth, yahoo-api

I am following oauth authorization flow(http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-requesttoken.html) for accessing Yahoo's Contact API . I am able to get consumer key and consumer secret for my application from first step.

However I am getting "File Not Found" in 2nd step while giving URI request.

My URI request is given below===>

https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/

get_request_token?oauth_nonce=rs2130523f788f313f76314ed3965ea6

&oauth_timestamp=1325661943

&oauth_consumer_key=dj0yJmk9VndXdnhUbkJMc2MyJmQ9WVdrOVUzcFdkbnA0TXpnbWNHbzlNamMxTXpJeU9UWXkm

cz1jb25zdW1lcnNlY3JldCZ4PTkw

&oauth_signature_method=plaintext

&oauth_signature=1daaeb467916f4331023fc5fce3cb6b6c27ac7ed

&oauth_version=1.0

&xoauth_lang_pref="en-us"

&oauth_callback="http://mysitename.freetzi.com/index.html"

Can you please tell why I am getting "File not found"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response status code is 401 if there is something wrong with your parameters. So you got the "File not found" error. But you can see the error message in the http header with Firebug. **Your problem is if the oauth_signature_method is plaintext, you should add a %26 after your oauth_signature** 
Like this
&oauth_signature_method=plaintext
**&oauth_signature=1daaeb467916f4331023fc5fce3cb6b6c27ac7ed%26** 
&oauth_version=1.0
Hope this helps.